# Mixed Content error request has been blocked

Tags: error, page-layout, publishing-page, https

We made a new page layout for publishing pages. Then we created a page for our portal with it. 
We linked javascript libs and css file **by relative server addresses**!
We can show the new page without error over http access.
But if someone tries to open the page by https a browser error is received:

[image: Error in Chrome Console]

Where to handle? Is this an issue of the page / page layout or a missconfig of web access / ISS?

The error seems not to come from our links but from the SP _api/contextInfo....!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved. There s been an hard coded http-link to a list inside one .js.file. So the SP-error message is not very precise just pointing on a context info api.